# Linking back to previous webpage?

Tags: navigation, hyperlinks, homepage, page

Currently the company I work for separates their company corporate website and their careers page. What this means is if you go to the parent site and click on the link to see career opportunities, you go to a completely different website. Both sites have similar designs but the navigation is different.

The problem we are having is linking back to the parent page. Currently, we are putting a link in the main nav on the careers page that says `parentpage.com` and from a usability perspective we don't feel that it is the best way to treat it. How can this can be solved and still be usable for our users?

Answer (score 3):

Conceptually, the link back to the main website lives at a different level from the main navigation of the current careers page. It's function is entirely different. So make it different and make it stand out.

You could put a bar at the top of the page that links to them could be a solution. Google uses this for instance, because all their services are part of the same environment.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwH30Z.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider the ["extra-site" navigation pattern](http://books.google.com/books?id=LC0cG-vFJbcC&pg=PA99&lpg=PA99&dq=extra%20site%20navigation&source=bl&ots=CWj5WudP79&sig=YGvTVzoIvcwe2gT7AfnJP2T0a8w&hl=en&sa=X&ei=4ESdUdfNBoXPigLc6YHIAw&ved=0CEAQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=extra%20site%20navigation&f=false).